# Is there a cleaner more organized or "pythonic" way for these print statements about a city?

Tags: python

Here I have a dictionary of dictionaries I omitted them but I am trying to have each city print out the follow with with proper alignment when the user types into the console the correct name. So far I've just been using a lot of `\t`'s which is fine, but seems rather messy, maybe there is a better way to use the `\t`'s or something else. Here is my code:

```
mydict = { 'Shenzhen' : {
    'Population': 14383936,
    'Category': 'want to visit',
    'Interesting Fact': 'was one of the fastest-growing cities in the world during the 1990s and the 2000s',
    'Geographic Coordinates': (22.542883, 114.062996)
            } }


if userInput == 'Shenzhen':
    print( '{0}:\t\t\t\t\t{1}'.format("City Name","Shenzhen") )
    print( "{0}:\t\t\t\t\t{1}".format( mydict['Shenzhen'].keys()[0], mydict['Shenzhen'].values()[0] ) )
    print( "{0}:\t\t\t{1}".format( mydict['Shenzhen'].keys()[1], mydict['Shenzhen'].values()[1] ) )
    print("{0}:\t\t\t\t\t{1}".format("Longitude", mydict['Shenzhen']['Geographic Coordinates'][0]))
    print("{0}:\t\t\t\t\t{1}".format("Latitude", mydict['Shenzhen']['Geographic Coordinates'][1]))
    print( "{0}:\t\t\t\t\t{1}".format( mydict['Shenzhen'].keys()[3], mydict['Shenzhen'].values()[3] ) )
```

I want it to print out evenly like:

```
City Name:     Shenzhen
Longitude:     2138530259
Latitude:      2302968049
Category:      Want to visit
```

and so on.

Comment: Avoid the WETness, see [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). For example, you could make a function that did the printing of one city, and then call it repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like the repetition of `\t` in your code, you can use the fact:

```
>>> '\t' * 4 == '\t\t\t\t'
True
```

For consistent alignment of integers or floats you can use the following syntax:

```
>>> print('{:5d}'.format(100))
  100
```

Here you indicate how many characters you want an integer/float that you are inserting into a string to take. Since `100` is only 3 characters, it will be displayed with 2 leading whitespaces.

You can read more on formatting print statements [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll just the \t*4 approach. What do you think of the multiple print statements, bad style?

Comment: @FooFighter What you are trying to do is basically print a table to a console. When I needed to do something similar, I used an external module - [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate). Not sure if there's a way to make table printing code look "nice" without using something like tabulate or wrtiting a simple table printing module yourself.